# Is it possible to access a sequence of one schema from another schema in PostgreSQL? If yes, then how?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence

Lets say, I have two database ***DatabaseA, DatabaseB*** and two schema **SchemaA** under *DatabaseA*, **SchemaB** under *DatabaseB*. Each Schema has a **User** table. So structure is like following image

[image: Structure of the database]

While inserting data into ***SchemaB.User*** I want to use the ***SchemaA.tablea_id_seq*** for primary key's value. How to achieve this?

Comment: Why? It's a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Lets say, two clients are going to use two database but there will be only one sequence.

Comment: Oh don't reinvent sharding :( What is your *specific* use case, and why won't referring to a single DB id work?